# Как обработать несколько ResultSet'ов, возвращаемых из одного запроса

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, resultset

Имеется маленькое андроид-приложение, в котором вызываются MSSQL-запросы.

Приходит ответ в `ResultSet`, но в нем отображается только первый курсор. Т.е. MSSQL-запрос возвращает 2 таблицы, а `Resultset` работает только с первой таблицей, насколько я понял.

Каким образом мне получить данные со второй таблицы?

**Процедура event_blank_s возвращает 2 столбца:**

```java
void lod_data_to_list() {
    try {
        ResultSet rs = Connection_Class.getdata("exec event_blank_s '10' , 1");
        values = new ArrayList();
        valuesid = new ArrayList();

        while (rs.next()) {
            values.add(rs.getString("name"));
            valuesid.add(rs.getInt("id_event"));
        }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
         adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        l_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Метод, который возвращает ResultSet**.

```java
public static ResultSet getdata(String text) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        //String query = text;
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(text);
        return rs;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("error here 2 : ", ex.getMessage() + "ResultSet getdata(Cionnection_Class)");
        return rs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как выглядит запрос?  если запрос возращает поля только из одной таблице, то скорее всего в запросе надо так же указать какие поля надо выводить из 2й таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, для обработки множественных результатов следует применять метод [`Statement::execute(String sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-), так как `Statement::executeQuery` возвращает только один ResultSet.

Во-вторых, для доступа к другим `ResultSet`'ам существует метод [`Statement::getMoreResults`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults--), который возвращает `true`, если следующий объект, возвращаемый из `Statement`, является результирующим набором.

По умолчанию данный метод закрывает текущий `ResultSet`.

Если нужно иметь несколько открытых результирующих наборов, следует вызывать метод [`Statement::getMoreResults(int current)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults-int-) с параметром [`Statement.KEEP_CURRENT_RESULT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#KEEP_CURRENT_RESULT), а по завершении работы со всеми наборами вызвать этот же метод с параметром [`Statement.CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#CLOSE_ALL_RESULTS).

Что касается чтения данных из базы, следует изолировать работу с базой в одном методе по принципу "один запрос -- одна сущность (entity)", при этом должен возвращаться экземпляр некоторого объекта, в который будут записаны необходимые данные из одного или нескольких ResultSet'ов.
Также следует закрывать `Statement`, используя `try-with-resources`.

Вариант чтения данных (код не тестировался):

```java
public MyEntity readEntity(Connection con, String query) {
    MyEntity result = new MyEntity();

    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
        boolean dataAvailable = stmt.execute(query);
        int rsCount = 0; 
        while (dataAvailable) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            if (rsCount == 0) {
                readFirstResultSet(result, rs);
            } else {
                readSecondResultSet(result, rs);
            }
            rsCount++;
            dataAvailable = stmt.getMoreResults();
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private void readFirstResultSet(MyEntity result, ResultSet rs) {
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        foos.add(new Foo(rs.getString("bar"), rs.getInteger("baz")));
    }
    result.setFoos(foos);
}

private void readSecondResultSet(MyEntity result, ResultSet rs) {
    if (rs.next()) {
        result.setMoo(rs.getString("moo"));
        result.setBoo(rs.getObject("boo"));
    }
}
```

Ссылки:

- [Пример использования множественных результатов для SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/jdbc/using-multiple-result-sets?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [Пример работы с известным количеством результатов, которые возвращаются хранимой процедурой с использованием `CallableStatement`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=rmrsfspija-retrieving-known-number-result-sets-from-stored-procedure-in-jdbc-application)

Comment: Запрос возвращает данные из 2-х таблиц но в дальнейшем есть запросы с более 2х таблиц. Поэтому вопрос более чем актуален. Сейчас попробую ваш метод. Спасибо огромное

Comment: Спасибо огромное получилось

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за наводку. Вот что у меня получилось

```
 public static ResultSet getdata_proc(String proc , int i_table_index)
    {
        ResultSet r_result = null;
        try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement();)
        {
            boolean results = stmt.execute(proc);
            int table_count = 0;
            do
            {
                if (results)
                {
                    r_result = stmt.getResultSet();

                    table_count++;
                    if(i_table_index == table_count)
                    {
                           return r_result;
                    }
                }
                results = stmt.getMoreResults();
            } while (results);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return r_result;
    }
```

Comment: Решение _немного странное_ -- допустим, ваша хранимая процедура читает данные из N таблиц и возвращает N резалтсетов, и для вычитки всех этих данных вам придётся вызвать метод `getdata_proc` тех же N раз, получив N² чтений из базы.

Comment: Если мне нужна именно вторая таблица , то вторым параметром я указываю индекс таблицы и в резулсет я получаю именно ту таблицу

Comment: Если индекс таблицы передается прямо в запросе `String proc`, то зачем тогда хранимой процедуре возвращать несколько резалтсетов?

Comment: Аналогичная программа работает у меня на виндовс , но там работать через DATASET намного проще. И переделывать базу специально под андройд не особо хочется.